# Is there a word for insulting yourself before someone else gets a chance to?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Some of you may have seen the Eminem film 8-mile, where he's in a rap battle, and at some point in the film he wins the rap battle by exhausting all the ammo about himself that his opponent was going to use so the opponent had nothing left to say.

I've seen this happen in real life a handful of times too, where a person who knows he's going to be insulted beats the other person to the punch and takes the wind out of their sails by doing so.

Is there any terms for this?

Comment: Related: [term for anticipating counterarguments and rebutting them](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/515761/term-for-anticipating-counterarguments-and-rebutting-them/515762#515762) (pre-emptive arguments; procatalepsis). // 'Come clean' doesn't carry the pre-emptive requirement.

Comment: Even 'jumping before you're pushed' doesn't really work; this time, too much of a hypernym.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I actually like that one quite a lot. It's not actually specific to the situation but it's an apt metaphor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took the wind right out of his sails by a by means of a thorough pre-emptive mea culpa.

Answer (score 2):

Such a remark against yourself could be described as [self-deprecating](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/self-deprecating#Adjective).

Comment: I'm looking for a word that implies that the *reason* for the self-deprecation is to pre-empt insults. It might be too specific of a meaning to have a word or phrase dedicated to this type of thing though.

Comment: @TKoL A phrase is more likely to exist than a single word here, but you need to add a tag and adjust your question to license an answer longer than a single word.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth edited with the tag, ty for pointing that out.

Comment: @TKoL 'self-deprecation' is exactly the single word for insulting yourself. 'disarming' is exactly the single word for removing an enemy's power over you. If you insist on the complicated concept being captured, there's no law that you have to use a single word.

Comment: @Mitch `there's no law that you have to use a single word` - yes, which is why in my exchange with Edwin I agreed that my tags should have included phrases.

Comment: @TKoL Sadly, I anticipate that there may not be even a fixed phrase capturing both concepts (self-deprecation w preemption). 'Preemptive self-deprecation' works, but, not being a fixed phrase, is a free combination (like pink car, fierce polecat ...), not on-topic on ELU

Answer (score 1):

An expression that may come close to capturing both parts of the OP's request is:

**steal someone's thunder** (idiom)

> To prevent someone from having success or getting attention, praise,
> etc., by doing or saying whatever that person was planning to do or
> say [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/steal%20someone%27s%20thunder)

> Win praise for oneself by preempting someone else's attempt to
> impress.
>
> Origin
> From an exclamation by the English dramatist John Dennis
> (1657–1734), who invented a method of simulating the sound of thunder
> as a theatrical sound effect and used it in an unsuccessful play.
> Shortly after his play came to the end of its short run he heard his
> new thunder effects used at a performance of Macbeth, whereupon he is
> said to have exclaimed: ‘Damn them! They will not let my play run, but
> they steal my thunder!’. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/steal_someone%27s_thunder)

> **Stealing thunder refers to a dissuasion tactic in which an individual
> reveals *potentially incriminating evidence* first, for the purpose of
> reducing its negative impact on an evaluative audience.** We examined
> whether it was necessary to frame the negative revelation in a manner
> that downplayed its importance, and found that stealing thunder
> successfully dissuaded mock jurors even without framing. We also
> sought to determine the mechanism by which stealing thunder operated,
> and found that **stealing thunder led mock jurors to change the meaning
> of incriminating evidence to be less damaging to the individual**. "[Stealing Thunder as a Courtroom Tactic
> Revisited](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/10718236_Stealing_Thunder_as_a_Courtroom_Tactic_Revisited_Processes_and_Boundaries)" (2003)